# Linechart under number 1 will produce a straight line at MPChart

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

recently i made crypto app,
when data value above 1 my linechart will look wavy, but when I'm showing data under 1, it will showing straight line.
I think this because value data under 1.

here's my screenshoot

[image]

how to make it wavy like the otherside?

thanks

Comment: Maybe you're inadvertently converting to an Int somewhere in your data manipulation so all your data points are y = 0.

Comment: lol, i don't know that was the problem. thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

As Tenfour04 said, i was inadvertently converting to an Int in my data.
problem solved